# Kleene Star Property : L*L* = L*

Tags: formal-languages

I am trying to prove this expression but don't have an exact idea about what to do:

If $E$ is any alphabet and $L$ is any language $L \subseteq E^*$. Prove that $L^*L^* = L^*$.

Comment: What have you tried?  This is a dump of an exercise problem, not a question. If you have a specific question regarding the wording of the problem or concrete steps in your own attempts at solving the problem, feel free to edit accordingly and we can reopen the question. See also [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/470/) for our homework policy, and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 4):

The standard approach to such proofs is:

1. Let $w \in L^*L^*$. This implies [...] and thus $w \in L^*$.
2. Let $w \in L^*$. This implies [...] and thus $w \in L^*L^*$.

Both parts combined give the proof of your statement. Does this help?

Comment: Thank you! Just one thing, how can i show that w ∈ L*L*?

Comment: @Ezgi In the second part? Note that $w$ is the same as $w$ concatenated with the empty word.